# Why am I unable to delete a firebase record from my application?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I originally had this working perfectly - adding/updating/deleting records. However, after adding some extra functionality the deleting of records is no longer possible.

I have been reading through the code for quite a while trying to figure out where I might have changed something, but to no avail.  Very frustrated.

At present, when I click the `delete` button in my application it shows the `Toast` message saying that the record has been deleted, but alas the record stays.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**PropertyActivity**

```
    package com.example.xxx.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PropertyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String PROPERTY_NAME = "propertyname";
    public static final String PROPERTY_ID = "propertyid";

    EditText editTextProperty;
    EditText editTextPostcode;
    EditText editTextBedrooms;
    EditText editTextBathrooms;
    Button buttonAddProperty;
    Spinner spinnerFuel;
    Spinner spinnerStatus;
    Spinner spinnerEPC;

    DatabaseReference databaseProperties;

    ListView listViewProperties;

    List<Property> propertyList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_property);

        databaseProperties = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("properties");

        editTextProperty = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProperty);
        editTextPostcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPostcode);
        editTextBedrooms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBedrooms);
        editTextBathrooms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextBathrooms);
        buttonAddProperty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddProperty);
        spinnerStatus = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerStatus);
        spinnerEPC = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerEPC);
        spinnerFuel = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFuel);

        listViewProperties = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProperties);

        propertyList = new ArrayList<>();

        buttonAddProperty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                addProperty();

            }
        });

        listViewProperties.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                Property property = propertyList.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddTenantsActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(PROPERTY_ID, property.getPropertyId());
                intent.putExtra(PROPERTY_NAME, property.getPropertyAddress());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listViewProperties.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Property property = propertyList.get(position);

                showUpdateDialog(property.getPropertyId(), property.getPropertyAddress(), property.getPropertyPostcode(), property.getPropertyBedrooms(), property.getPropertyBathrooms(), property.getPropertyStatus(), property.getPropertyEPC(), property.getPropertyFuel());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseProperties.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                propertyList.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot propertySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Property property = propertySnapshot.getValue(Property.class);

                    propertyList.add(property);

                }

                PropertyList adapter = new PropertyList (PropertyActivity.this, propertyList);
                listViewProperties.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void showUpdateDialog(final String id, String propertyAddress, String propertyPostcode, String propertyBedrooms, String propertyBathrooms, String propertyStatus, final String propertyId, String propertyName) {

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);

        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText editTextName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        final EditText editTextPostcode = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextPostcode);
        final EditText editTextBedrooms = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextBedrooms);
        final EditText editTextBathrooms = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextBathrooms);
        final Button buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
        final Spinner spinnerStatus = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerStatus);
        final Spinner spinnerEPC = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerEPC);
        final Spinner spinnerFuel = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerFuel);
        final Button buttonDelete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Updating Property " + propertyName);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
                String postcode = editTextPostcode.getText().toString().trim();
                String bedrooms = editTextBedrooms.getText().toString().trim();
                String bathrooms = editTextBathrooms.getText().toString().trim();
                String status = spinnerStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String epc = spinnerEPC.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String fuel = spinnerFuel.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

                    editTextName.setError("Name Required");
                    return;
                }

                updateProperty(propertyId, status, postcode, bedrooms, bathrooms, id, name, epc, fuel);

                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deleteProperty(propertyId);
            }
        });
    }

    private void deleteProperty(String propertyId) {
        DatabaseReference drProperty = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("properties").child(propertyId);
        DatabaseReference drTenants = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants").child(propertyId);

        drProperty.removeValue();
        drTenants.removeValue();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Property has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private boolean updateProperty(String propertyId, String status, String postcode, String bedrooms, String bathrooms, String id, String name, String epc, String fuel){

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("properties").child(id);
        Property property = new Property (id, name, postcode, bedrooms, bathrooms, status, epc, fuel);

        databaseReference.setValue(property);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Property Updated Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }

    private void addProperty(){

        String address = editTextProperty.getText().toString().trim();
        String postcode = editTextPostcode.getText().toString().trim();
        String bedrooms = editTextBedrooms.getText().toString().trim();
        String bathrooms = editTextBathrooms.getText().toString().trim();
        String status = spinnerStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String epc = spinnerEPC.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String fuel = spinnerFuel.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(address)){

            String id = databaseProperties.push().getKey();

            Property property = new Property (id, address, postcode, bedrooms, bathrooms, status, epc, fuel);

            databaseProperties.child(id).setValue(property);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Property Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter a property", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO. Please try to avoid submitting code that long. It is usually suffice to cite 5-10 lines that do the job. On the way to this you could find a solution yourself. If not, that code would be much easier to understand for others. This increases the chance to get quick and relevant answer. Particularly, your question is about DB - so what does UI code do in here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the arguments passed to `showUpdateDialog()` are mismatched.  The method accepts eight arguments.  The first six are not used (?) and the last two are `propertyId` and `propertyName`.  When the method is called from `onItemLongClick()`, the values for `propertyId` and `propertyName` are `property.getPropertyEPC()`, `property.getPropertyFuel()`.

I suspect this results in a bad value for `propertyId`, which is passed to `deleteProperty()` and used to create the database reference for the location to be removed.

When your code isn't working and the problem cannot be found by inspection, it's always a good idea to add [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) statements to trace the execution flow and output the values of relevant variables.  The output can be [viewed in logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).  It's also good practice to include a [CompletionListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener) on your database operations to get an indication of success or failure.  For example:

```
private void deleteProperty(String propertyId) {
    Log.d("PropertyActivity", "deleteProperty: propertyId=" + propertyId);

    DatabaseReference drProperty = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("properties").child(propertyId);
    DatabaseReference drTenants = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tenants").child(propertyId);

    drProperty.removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError == null) {
                Log.d("PropertyActivity", "Property remove complete");
            } else {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        }
    });

    drTenants.removeValue();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Property has been deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```